# overflow: auto not working in Safari OSX

Tags: html, css, scroll, safari, overflow

I have an off-canvas navigation (using [Zurb Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/offcanvas.html)) and I have the overflow set to `auto` so the user can scroll if the menu is long.

It is currently **working on the following browsers:**

- Chrome
- Firefox
- Internet Explorer
- Android Chrome
- Safari iOS

but **not on Safari for OS X**:
It treats the menu like overflow is `hidden` and does not scroll.

Here is the HTML menu:

```
<!-- Off Canvas Menu -->
        <aside class="right-off-canvas-menu">
            <ul class="side-nav" role="navigation" title="Main Navigation" onmouseover="this.title='';">
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li role="menuitem" class="active-parent">
                    <a href="#">Agriculture & Natural Resources</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li role="menuitem" class="active"><a href="third-level.html">Home & Garden</a></li>
                        <ul>
                            <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Lawn & Garden Tips</a></li>
                            <li role="menuitem"><a href="fourth-level.html">Garden Q&A</a></li>
                            <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Ponds</a></li>
                            <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Turfgrass & Calendar</a></li>
                            <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Weeds</a></li>
                            <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Insects</a></li>
                            <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Invasive Plants</a></li>
                            <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Wildlife</a></li>
                            <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Gold Medal Plants</a></li>
                            <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Finding Arborists</a></li>
                            <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Finding Landscapers</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Plant Material</a></li>
                        <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Diagnostic Testing</a></li>
                        <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Green Industry</a></li>
                        <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Publications</a></li>
                        <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Newsletters</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Family & Consumer Sciences</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">4-H Youth</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Events</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
            </ul>
        </aside>
```

And here is the sass:

```
// Off Canvas
// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

.right-off-canvas-menu {
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100vh;
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Comment: If anyone is curious, I've nearly solved it.  Adding margin and padding code seem to help it work fine in Safari for OS X, but I am having a strange issue where Safari on iOS ignores the overflow:hidden property on another element. But this appears to fix the problem at hand.  `.right-off-canvas-menu {
        height: 100%;
        max-height: 100vh;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: auto;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    }`

Answer (score 15):

`overflow: auto;` and `overflow: scroll;` seem to work different on iOS and OS X. Try to use `overflow: scroll;` plus `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` on iOS and OS X.

Maybe these resources will assist you:

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow/

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/momentum-scrolling-on-ios-overflow-elements/

https://benfrain.com/horizontal-scrolling-area-css-overflow-ios/

Comment: Confirmed. Using overflow: scroll seems to have fixed it. I had overflow:auto set before. Thx

Comment: what if you only wanna show scroll when it's needed? Seems like a safari bug if the scrolls don't act the same when they show. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Yes, bug is always there (Safari v14.0.3 on Mac OS). I do not want always visible scroller but Safari has problem with primitive old "auto".

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```css
white-space:nowrap;
overflow: scroll;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this question from a Google search when trying to fix the same type of issue in my own project, but the solutions here have not solved the scroll bar disappearing, but the solution in [this site](https://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/scrollbars/) solved it for me.

So adapting it to the div you want to show the scroll bar with `auto` behavior:

```css
:root {
  --scrollbar-track-color: transparent;
  --scrollbar-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);

  --scrollbar-size: .375rem;
  --scrollbar-minlength: 1.5rem; /* Minimum length of scrollbar thumb (width of horizontal, height of vertical) */
}
.right-off-canvas-menu::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: var(--scrollbar-size);
  width: var(--scrollbar-size);
}
.right-off-canvas-menu::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: var(--scrollbar-track-color);
}
.right-off-canvas-menu::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: var(--scrollbar-color);
  /* Add :hover, :active as needed */
}
.right-off-canvas-menu::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical {
  min-height: var(--scrollbar-minlength);
}
.right-off-canvas-menu::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
  min-width: var(--scrollbar-minlength);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it worked when I set a `display` (used inline-block but others worked as well) property to the element's children.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is IOS specific we can target safari ios and add css attribute such as `overflow: scroll;` to fix the issue.

```
 @supports (-webkit-touch-callout: none) {
           .classname{
                       white-space:nowrap;
                       overflow: scroll;
                       -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;  
                     }
                     }
```

Answer (score 0):

**this issue wasn't solved when I had added :**

```
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  white-space:nowrap;
```

**To solve it in Safari** and to add scrolling in div:

1- make sure to add: `overflow-y: scroll;` and not `overflow-y: auto;` because it seems they have different effect in Safari .

2- Then if you are specifying height for that div, don't add overflow properties inside that div. Instead, make another nested div and add overflow properities there like this:

**html :**

```
<div class="main"> 
  <div class=""scrollable> </div>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
.main{
 height: 93vh;
}
. scrollable{
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that some pointer events were disabled in Safari (still unclear why), so fixed it by adding `pointer-events:all` to the scrolling container.

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite old, so it might not be the same problem, but this might help other people searching for similar issues:

In my case, with `overflow-y: auto`, I was not able to scroll using the mouse wheel on macOS Safari, even though the scroll bar was there and I was able to drag the scroll bar.

The solution was to "flick" the `pointer-events` property between two values (`element` is the scrollable DOM element):

```js
element.style.setProperty('pointer-events', 'none');
setTimeout(() => {
      element.style.setProperty('pointer-events', 'auto');
    },
    0);
```